# Suppress compiler warnings on JAXB generated classes

Tags: java, jaxb, xjc, annox, jaxb2-annotate-plugin

This is possibly a duplicate of this question ([Avoiding Compiler warnings on code generated by xjc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19917257/avoiding-compiler-warnings-on-code-generated-by-xjc)) but since I am not very well versed in XJC/JAXB custom bindings idiosyncrasies, I'll presume I may have misunderstood the mentioned question.

My question seems simple enough - how can I add `@SuppressWarnings("all")` annotation to generated JAXB class? We have 0 warning policy on our project and after JAXB generation step, we end up with 350+ warnings which are just terrible noise.

I would expect either a simple flag on the XJC or at least an easy way to provide such info but I cannot find any.

From what I've seen in my travels, people do one of these things:

1. @lexicore's [JAXB2 Annotate Plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) which, according to examples, seems to do the job but to add a whole *framework* and hundreds of kB of code just to add simple annotation to a bunch of classes? Really??,
2. Custom JAXB bindings (I may be mistaken but this seems very arcane and I am not fully sure if it were event possible to do it this way),
3. Custom ANT target which will do a search-and-replace post-JAXB generation,
4. Eclipse 4+ seems to have an option to filter out warnings on selected projects but for various historical/legacy reasons we're stuck on Eclipse 3.7.2 (Indigo),
5. Custom XJC plugin which would do the annotation insertion (as suggested by one of the commenters, see [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxb/developPlugins.html)),
6. Placing all of the generated classes in a JAR, making the JAR a dependency of the project and then removing generated code altogether.

Formerly, we dealt with this by shoving the XML-related code in a separate Eclipse project and then disabling the warnings/errors on the project. Now, as part of code consolidation/refactoring, we've reshuffled things around and no longer have that luxury.

Is there really no elegant solution for such a seemingly trivial problem? Any feedback/thoughts are greatly appreciated.

FWIW, our project uses Ant as build system.

Comment: How many different kinds kf warnings are you getting on your generated JAXB model?

Comment: About 95% of warnings can be broken down to two categories. One is about extranous generic type declaration (JAXB doesn't use the Java 7 diamond operator) and the other one is about non-nls String literals not being externalized. There are a few others and generally we don't care about any of them.

Comment: We have the same issue and are using option 4 in our project. If you think Atkassuans plugin is too large, you might want to create your own plugin that just add that annotation. It should only be a few code lines. You might even publicize it so we all can get rid of this problem :). See
http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17802_01/webservices/webservices/docs/2.0/jaxb/developPlugins.html

Comment: @BlaiseDoughan FYI, I'm getting a bunch of "Dead Code" warnings from the plugin that makes `toString()`, `hashCode()` and `equals()`.

Comment: @flaschenpost Agreed - it seems like the least fussy and "most proper" solution at present.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use this plugin : [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin)

2 solutions :

1 - Modify your xsd and add this kind of block

```
<xsd:element name="foobar" type="xsd:string">
    <xsd:annotation>
        <xsd:appinfo>
            <annox:annotate>@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all")</annox:annotate>
        </xsd:appinfo>
    </xsd:annotation>
</xsd:element>
```

2 - Create a custom binding

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<jaxb:bindings
    xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:xjc="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/xjc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:annox="http://annox.dev.java.net"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
    jaxb:extensionBindingPrefixes="xjc annox"
    version="2.1">
    <jaxb:bindings schemaLocation="schema.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
        <annox:annotate target="class">@java.lang.SuppressWarnings("all")</annox:annotate>
    </jaxb:bindings>
</jaxb:bindings>
```

Comment: Thanks for detailed answer, especially the correct syntax in the custom binding.

Answer (score 5):

**Disclaimer**: I am the author of the [jaxb2-annotate-plugin](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin) mentioned in @ToYonos answer.

This is not a standalone answer but rather an addition to @ToYonos answer.

I would like to address the following point from the question.

> 1. Annox plugin from Atlassian's JAXB2 Basics framework/project (according to examples, seems to do the job but to add a whole
>      framework and hundreds of kB of code just to add simple annotation to
>      a bunch of classes? Really??),

I just need to add a few notes:

- First of all, this is not "Atlassian's" framework/project. I am neither employee nor affiliated with Atlassian or Sun or Oracle (although I'm an official Sun/Oracle contributor). This is an indipendent open-source project not driven by any company.
- Next, `jaxb2-annotate-plugin` was moved to a [standalone project](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-annotate-plugin), it is not longer part of [JAXB2 Basics](https://github.com/highsource/jaxb2-basics). It just got too large and deserved to be a standalone thing.
- Concerning "a whole framework and hundreds of kB of code".

  - **`jaxb2-annotate-plugin` does not require or add ANY *runtime* dependencies to your code**. If you annotations have runtime retention, you'll need the classes of your annotations in runtime, but it should be obvious.
  - `jaxb2-annotate-plugin` does indeed have a number of *compile-time* dependencies like [javaparser](/questions/tagged/javaparser) which is used to parse annotations from Java syntax. Well, this is due to the fact the plugin has to do a lot of moderately advanced stuff like parse annotations from Java syntax and transform them to [codemodel](/questions/tagged/codemodel) to add to the generated code. I personally don't think that a few hundred kBs in the compile time is a problem at all.

So, from my point of view, @ToYonos offered a reasonable *workaround* for the moment.

---

Now, how would a correct fix look like?

- The correct fix would be to fix XJC. Everything else is just a workaround.
- There is the [JAXB-1053](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-1053) issue for this problem. Iaroslav correctly points out that as long as `1.6` has to be supported, the diamond fix can't be applied.
- The [CodeModel](https://codemodel.java.net/) will have to be updated as well to support Java 7+ constructs.
- You could help by forking and providing a PR to XJC code [on GitHub](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb). However I could not say that PRs really do get applied. There are three of my PRs [in the pipeline](https://github.com/gf-metro/jaxb/pulls), for a month or so already.
- It is possible to write an XJC plugin which would override code generation. This is not easy but possible.

The correct fix does not look like an easy task, I'd opt to a workaround and wait for the vendor fix at the moment.

Comment: Ah, I also found JAXB-1053, but I completely disagree with "can't be applied yet". Maybe I'm very old-school, but once upon a time there have been command-line options to enable one program to create different outputs. Unfortunately I can't write that in JAXB-1053 (since I'm not member of that forum).

Comment: @flaschenpost You can register on java.net, this is not a problem. Concerning the CLI option to produce warnings-free code on - well, this is surely an option but also an additional configuration dimension. I don't say it's impossible, it's just effort. And what you alsways have to consider is that Oracle faces huge "don't break existing solutions" responsibility on customer-facing APIs (XJC being one of them).

Comment: @lexicore Thanks, I didn't intend to be bashful in any way with my remarks - it simply seemed like an complete overkill for such a trivial use case. I was convinced there had to be an easy solution without external deps which I had overlooked but turns out there isn't. However, I have amended my question with ownership clarification. I have also added a couple of other workarounds we were considering. In the end, we migrated to Eclipse 4.4 and hid the warnings but I didn't think such solution warrants a separate answer. I have up-voted both your answers (they propose reasonable solution(s)).

Comment: @Quantum No, no, don't worry, I did not interpret it as "bashful". :) I just wanted to update the topic to the current state of affairs and add a clarification on a few things. No worries. :)

Comment: @Quantum I also think that your question and approaches you listed provide valuable context to the interested users. Thumbs up. :)

Comment: At the time of writing, [JAXB-1053](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAXB-1053) only has **one** vote (by me, a moment ago).  I suggest that all those who think this is important should also vote for the issue.