# Compile warnings setting on java buildpath in eclipse reverts after maven "update project"

Tags: eclipse, maven, code-generation, compiler-warnings, buildpath

Whenever I do a maven update project (<kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>f5</kbd>), the setting "Ignore optional compile problems" revert to "No". This annoys the heck out of me since it is generated sources which i cant fix.

Anyone know how to make it stick?

[image]

Comment: Have you seen this: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=388541 ?

Comment: No I have not, thanks. Didn't help me much though :)

Answer (score 0):

Another solution to the problem is to add suppressions to the generated clases using a plugin called  jaxb2-annotate-plugin

[Suppress compiler warnings on JAXB generated classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22314669/suppress-compiler-warnings-on-jaxb-generated-classes)